# Django registration different type users with different fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I need to create two different users: `Gym` and `Client`. The client should theoretically be connected by a many-to-many bond because he can be enrolled in multiple gyms. My doubt is about user registration. I found this around:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_gym = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Gym(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.is_gym = True

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gyms = models.ManyToManyField(Gym, related_name='clients')
    user.is_client = True

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.is_gym:
            Gym.objects.create(user=instance)
        elif instance.is_client:
            Client.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_gym:
        instance.gym.save()
    elif instance.is_client:
        instance.client.save()
```

My doubts are two:

- If I wanted to register users with a button "I am a gym" or "I am a customer" with this code, theoretically I could not do it because `User` class differs, the gym does not have a surname for example.
- With this code I should create the `Gym` and `Client` class populated at a later time so I should make a second form after verifying the account.

Comment: you can use 1 user model. add all the fields of gym and client to the same user model. you can then clean and check what data you need for each type of user and your users can just switch account type. look at how udemy handles its users. there are students and instructors but you only need to register once. I think that type of user handling can support what you want.

Comment: also check this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) on your problem

Comment: In this way it will be more difficult for me to obtain and manage which customers registered to one or more gyms or am I wrong?

Comment: I believe it would be easier. I think Joshua said a good solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would push a lot of that information onto the `Gym` and `Client` models, as you say, a gym doesn't have a surname. You could use the base `User` model for authentication and set the username to an email address. The `Client` model can then have fields for first name, surname, and anything else. The `Gym` model would just have a name field.

In terms of managing this, you can create a form for both profiles and render one depending on whether the User clicks gym or client in the next view.

Answer (score 1):

For this i advice you make the **Gym** a separate model instead of a user model, especially if **Gym** here is not a person. Then when you can create a new model for **Gym** with the mentality that this model is representing a building, then inside that model you add a foreign key for the **User** or make it a ManyToMany field. You can make it null if you know the **Gym** wont at all times have a **User** connected(Lets say on registration for example the field may not be field instantly). By doing this you should make a registration for a base user and after registration you now give the user a choice if he wants to be a **Client** or own a **Gym**. What can help you in this is the **Groups** and **Permissions** feature on Django

Comment: Under your advice, I was thinking about creating a unique user model where there are gym owners and customers. A has_gym attribute will allow me to define the rest. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Oh in that case, create two groups called gym_owner and customer. that way base on what group you belong you have access and can do particular things. This way you can check the user model in every request if he/she has the particular group you want. something like "if request.user.groups.filter(name="gym_owner") is True "

Comment: using groups is better than having a field in the user model like has_gym which you said above. That method will make it hard to scale, but with groups u can easily add new roles and permission and u have more functionality